# CSS Flexbox - scroll not visible with overflow-scroll: y

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style='overflow: hidden;'>
<style>
        *, :after, :before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .example {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }

        .bottom {
            overflow: auto;
            height: 140px;
            max-height: 100%;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }

        .top {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
        }

        .scroll {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .elements {
            position: relative;
        }
        .test {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
<article class="example">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="scroll">
            <article class="elements">
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
                <article class="test">
                    TEST
                </article>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <article class="bottom">
        Bottom
    </article>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that "Bottom" text is always visible, and area with "Test" element is scrollable - but scroll is not working. Would you like to spent a minute and help me to figure it out? Thank you in advance for every help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit changes to your code

```css
*,
 :after,
 :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* some normalization to document */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.example {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 140px;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

/* handling overflow here */

.top {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* removed overflow here */

.scroll {
  width: 100%;
}

.elements {
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article class="example">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="scroll">
      <article class="elements">
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
        <article class="test">
          TEST
        </article>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article class="bottom">
    Bottom
  </article>
</article>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, the only one change is handling scroll one level up, am I right?

Comment: You should explain what exactly did you change, it can be helpful for the person who asked the question and other people who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a height set for the article container ( and you can use overflow: auto; too ).

```
.elements {
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
   height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I did it for example purpose (for real case, it has about 150px height)